# Print Ansible variable to command line from ad-hoc command

Tags: ansible

I currently have a YAML file which defines several variables:

```
variable_a: some_value_1
variable_b: some_value_2
variable_c: some_value_3
```

Is there any ad hoc command I can run from the terminal that will allow me to selectively print the value of each of these variables? E.g.

```
ansible --file=my_file.yml --print-var=variable_a
```

would print

```
some_value_1
```

I need to access these variables inside a bash script, so I can't just use `include_vars`.

Comment: did you already try `ansible -m debug -a var=variable_a`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pass your variables file with the `--extra-vars` or `-e` option for the ad-hoc command.

Given a YAML file with variables `my_vars.yml`

```yaml
variable_a: some_value_1
variable_b: some_value_2
variable_c: some_value_3
```

Run ad-hoc command:

```
~$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "var=variable_a" -e @my_vars.yml

localhost | SUCCESS => {
  "variable_a": "some_value_1"
}
```

If you want to trim the output:

```
~$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "var=variable_a" -e @my_vars.yml | grep variable_a | awk '{print $2}'
"some_value_1"
```